# Externally timing an async method passed via param?

Tags: c#, .net

Right now, I have the following code that times the completion time of a method and prints it out:

```
    static void Run()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        GetTableNames().Wait();
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
    }

    static async Task GetTableNames() { doesStuff(); }
```

However, I'll be reusing that timing code a bunch, so I'd like to wrap it inside a method so that I can do something like this:

```
static void Run()
{
    TimeMethod(GetTableNames);
    TimeMethod(GetChairNames);
    TimeMethod(GetStoolNames);
    // etc...
}
```

I've been trying a few different things (Action, Delegate, Func), but haven't succeeded in finding one that allows me to call .Wait() on the passed function before stopping the timer.  Any recommendations?

Comment: How's `GetTableNames` declared?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek At the bottom of that first code block ^ static async Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `TimeMethod` to take `Func<Task>`:

```
TimeMethod(Func<Task> method)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    method().Wait();
    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
}
```

Comment: Cool; that worked.  I kept trying to stick async somewhere in the declaration.  Thanks!